# System.DLLNotFoundException when calling Haskell from C# on Linux (wsl1 Debian)

Tags: c#, haskell

I need some things from a Haskell library, so I'm trying to write a little wrapper to call the stuff I need from C#. However, when trying to compile, I get errors about a missing Windows dll, as well as an undefined symbol error that I haven't been able to find anything useful about online.

Haskell code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module GFWrapper where

import GF(batchCompile, getOptions, ModuleName, Grammar)
import Data.Time(UTCTime)

import Foreign.C.String
-- import Foreign.C.Types

compile :: CString -> IO Int
compile cstr =
          do
          str <- peekCString cstr
          wrapper_compile (str : [])
          return 0

wrapper_compile :: [FilePath] -> IO (UTCTime, (ModuleName, Grammar)) 
wrapper_compile files = (fst <$> getOptions) >>= (\x -> batchCompile x files)

foreign export ccall compile :: CString -> IO Int
```

compiled with: `ghc -O2 -dynamic -shared -fPIC -o GFWrapper.so GFWrapper.hs`

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CSharpGF {
    class Program {

        [DllImport("GFWrapper.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern void hs_init(IntPtr argc, IntPtr argv);

        [DllImport("GFWrapper.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern void hs_exit();

        [DllImport("GFWrapper.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int compile(string str);

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Initializing runtime...");
            hs_init(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

            try {
                Console.WriteLine("Calling to Haskell...");
                int result = compile("FoodEng.gf");
                Console.WriteLine("Got result: {0}", result);
            } finally {
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting runtime...");
                hs_exit();
            }
        }
    }
```

I ran with `LD_DEBUG=libs dotnet run` and got this:

```
      3404:     /usr/lib/ghc/ghc-prim-0.5.2.0/libHSghc-prim-0.5.2.0-ghc8.4.4.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: stg_gc_unpt_r1 (fatal)
Unhandled exception.       3404:        find library=Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll [0]; searching
      3404:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      3404:      search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib:/usr/lib              (system search path)
      3404:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
      3404:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
      3404:       trying file=/lib/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
      3404:       trying file=/usr/lib/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
      3404:
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'GFWrapper.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: /usr/lib/ghc/ghc-prim-0.5.2.0/libHSghc-prim-0.5.2.0-ghc8.4.4.so: undefined symbol: stg_gc_unpt_r1
   at CSharpGF.Program.hs_init(IntPtr argc, IntPtr argv)
```

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr I got it to work but only by compiling on Windows...

I managed to get calling it from C to work. Figured I could then look into calling C from C# and all would be well, but I ended up getting "symbol not found" errors about hs_init.

Eventually I ended up stumbling on https://blog.mgattozzi.dev/rust-haskell/ which links Haskell to Rust through C. Didn't work, the library it uses has since broken, but I adapted it to properly import from Haskell to C# through C.

Aaand I got the same errors as I described in the original question again. But I now knew how to build a shared lib with stack, which meant I could get the old stack snapshot I needed to get this to build on Windows.

And lo and behold, it worked on Windows. So I guess I'm doing this on Windows now.